# Chart.js - Hover popup - Adding labels with values - not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good morning.  I'm working with Chart.js and have it set up to produce a nice bar chart.  Unfortunately, the default popup when you hover over the bars only shows the color of the bar and it's value.  The color of the bar is unhelpful to our users.  I would like the popup to display the label of each bar in the group and its value.  Sort of like:

First Project : 80
Second project : 25
Third project : 64

There have been other posts about this issue and they recommended using
    multiTooltipTemplate : "<%%=datasetLabel%> : <%%=value%>"

I tried it but it had no effect.  No errors but no change to the popup.  Perhaps it isn't set up correctly.  Any suggestions?

```
$.post(url, dataObject)
.done(function (results) {

    if (results.length > 0) {

        //Build mydatasets empty array
        var mydatasets = [];

        //Loop through the results and build a new data array object to be added to the master data array object that will
        //be assigned to the chart bars.
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {

            var dataset =
                {
                    label : results[i].WorkTypeName,
                    fillColor : getRandomColor(),  //Found in the ChartHelpers.js file
                    data : results[i].Hours
                }

            mydatasets.push(dataset);
        }

        //Plug the data into the data structure
        var data = {
            labels: startdates, 
            datasets: mydatasets
        };

        //Get chart context
        var ctx = $("#myChart").get(0).getContext("2d");

        // This will get the first returned node in the jQuery collection and use it to create a bar chart
        myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            options: {
                multiTooltipTemplate : "<%%=datasetLabel%> : <%%=value%>"
            }
        }).Bar(data);

    }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer with some additional experimentation!  Other forum posts had suggested using

```
multiTooltipTemplate : "<%%=datasetLabel%> : <%%=value%>"
```

in the options.  that generated a syntax error message.  Removing the extra two percent signs caused the popup to display as planned.

```
multiTooltipTemplate : "<%=datasetLabel%> : <%=value%>"
```